# Using css to build a polygon with images on each vertex

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to use css to build a response web page like below:
[image: circles to form a polygon]

I have those 5 circles ready, I can use polygon css to build the polygon, but how can I put each circle on the vertex of the polygon? Also there are two arched arrow on the side, Is there a way to elegantly position them?

Comment: your link isn't a link.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/